# compare 3 ranges instead of 2

Tags: excel, vba, udf

```
Public Function Compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Long
   Dim r As Range, v As Variant, v2 As Variant
   Dim rr As Range
   For Each r In r1
      v = r.Value
      If v <> 0 And v <> "" Then
         For Each rr In r2
            v2 = rr.Value
            If v = v2 Then Compare = Compare + 1
         Next rr
      End If
   Next r
End Function
```

This UDF compares 2 ranges and return the number of matched values. 
I would like to compare 3 ranges instead, in order to find how many values appeared in all 3 ranges simultaneously.

Much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Public Function Compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Long
   Dim r As Range, v As Variant, m1 As Variant, m2 As Variant
   Dim rv As Long

   rv = 0
   For Each r In r1
      v = r.Value
      If v <> 0 And v <> "" And Not IsError(v) Then
            m1 = Application.Match(v, r2, 0)
            m2 = Application.Match(v, r3, 0)
            If Not IsError(m1) And Not IsError(m2) Then
               rv = rv + 1
            End If
      End If
   Next r
   Compare = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This functions works fine for me, tell me if you need some improvement.

```
Public Function Compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Long
    Dim i
    Dim v1
    Dim v2
    Dim v3
    Dim counter

    counter = 0
    For Each i In r1
        counter = counter + 1
        v1 = r1(counter).Value
        v2 = r2(counter).Value
        v3 = r3(counter).Value

        If v1 = v2 And v2 = v3 Then
            'r3(counter).Offset(0, 2).Value = "OK" 'this is for the test
            Compare = Compare + 1
            'I think could be easy to test and return a value...
            'Compare = v1 'Because is the same value in the 3 cells
        Else
            'r3(counter).Offset(0, 2).Value = "NO"'this is for the test
            'Do another code...

        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

**Edit #1**

This could help...

```
Public Function Compare2(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Long
    Dim i
    Dim v1
    Dim v2
    Dim v3
    Dim counter
    Dim n1 As Range
    Dim n2 As Range
    Dim n3 As Range
    Dim max

    counter = 0
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(r1.Count, r2.Count, r3.Count)
    'With "max" take the max number of rows in the range to use it

    Set n1 = Range(Cells(r1(1).Row, r1(1).Column), Cells(r1(1).Row + max - 1, r1(1).Column))
    Set n2 = Range(Cells(r2(1).Row, r2(1).Column), Cells(r2(1).Row + max - 1, r2(1).Column))
    Set n3 = Range(Cells(r3(1).Row, r3(1).Column), Cells(r3(1).Row + max - 1, r3(1).Column))
    'Here we set new ranges, equals all of them, to use them in the for loop and compare
    'we use the ref of the input ranges.

    counter = 0
    For Each i In n1
        counter = counter + 1 'this is the index for the new ranges
        v1 = n1(counter).Value 'store every value of the new ranges
        v2 = n2(counter).Value
        v3 = n3(counter).Value

        If v1 = v2 And v2 = v3 Then 'do the comparison, and if the 3 values are equal
            'n3(counter).Offset(0, 2).Value = "OK" 'this is just for the test
            Compare2 = Compare2 + 1 'add 1 to compare
        Else
            'n3(counter).Offset(0, 2).Value = "NO"
            'this part of the code don't do anything
            'but if you want to put some code is up to you.
            'You can delete from Else to this comment
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Added more comments to the function.

Comment: Won't this only work if the values are in the exact same order?  What if one list is longer than another list?

Comment: I get #VALUE!...All lists are different in size and values are not in exact same order

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative for a non-vba solution.

Consider a data layout like so:

[image: sample.jpg]

In cell E2 is this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(B2:B16,A2:A23)>0),--(COUNTIF(C2:C19,A2:A23)>0))
```

I have highlighted all of the cells that have matches in all three columns for clarity.  There are a total of 8 cells in column A that have duplicates found in columns B and C.  Note that this will count duplicates in column A (but so does your UDF already).